# You may need to configure your browser or application to trust the Charles Root Certificate. See - iOS Native app not working with Charles

Tags: charles-proxy

Charles: 4.2.6 , iOS: 10.2, Mac OS: 10.13.5

Followed instructions mentioned under https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/, but getting same error

"You may need to configure your browser or application to trust the Charles Root Certificate. See SSL Proxying in the Help menu."

Am I doing something wrong or this is bug in latest charles ?

Comment: https://vikramviknowledgesharing.wordpress.com/2017/01/01/appium-mobile-automation/

Answer (score 25):

**For iOS Simulator**

Goto: Settings --> General --> About --> Certificate Trust Settings
[image]

Comment: tried this and now resetting my simulator and again doin the same process :D Good luck

Answer (score 15):

On your iPhone, Go to General-> About -> (Scroll down to bottom) Certificate Trust Settings -> Trust the Charles Proxy Certificate

Answer (score 8):

You need to go to Certificate Trust Settings -> Enable Full trust for Root Certificates . Turn the slider on to enable full trust for the Charles Proxy Custom Root Certificate, this should fix it.