# You may need to configure your browser or application to trust the Charles Root Certificate

Tags: ios, proxy, charles-proxy

Charles was setup and worked fine on my iPhone. Without changing anything (at least what I know of) neither on iphone nor mac one day it started givinig me the SSL handshake failed error:

```
You may need to configure your browser or application to trust the Charles Root Certificate
```

I tried to re-install Charles on the mac and re-setup the iphone (including trying another device, same iOS version). But the problem remains.

Seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51543270/you-may-need-to-configure-your-browser-or-application-to-trust-the-charles-root), the certificate was trusted both before and after the problem.

iOS: 16.6, mac OS: Ventura 13.4.1, Charles: 4.6.4

Did anyone have the same or does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Is it possible that you use "iCloud Private Relay"?

Comment: No, I don't have that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the case that choosing "Install Charles Root Certificate in iOS Simulators" does not work.

First check whether the simulator itself confirms that the certificate really is not there.

Open Settings -> General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings

You probably won't see the certificate yet.

Open this URL on your simulator's Safari: http://chls.pro/ssl
(This URL is hosted by your local Charles client and you can download the certificate from that URL via browser.)

The simulator will show a prompt and ask you whether you want to install the certificate. Confirm. Now you should be able to see the certificate in the trust settings and the proxy will work.